# Having problems unit testing a promise call in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

`SupportedLanguagesServices` get method returns a `promise` which is resolved in the controller as follows:

```
    angular.module('App').controller('MyController', ['SupportedLanguagesService',
    function(SupportedLanguagesService) {

        var self = this;
        self.supportedLanguages = [];

        SupportedLanguagesService.get().success(
            function(response) {
                self.supportedLanguages = response;
        });

    }]);
```

And here is the test I wrote, but it is not working:

```
    describe('Controller: MyController', function() {

    beforeEach(module('App'));

    var rootScope, controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, SupportedLanguagesService, $q) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve([{name:"English", code:"en"},{name:"Portugues", code:"pt_BR"]);
        spyOn(SupportedLanguagesService, 'get').andReturn(deferred.promise);

        rootScope = $rootScope;
        controller = $controller;
    }));

    it('should get SupportedLanguages', function() {
        rootScope.$digest();
        var ctrl = controller('MyController');
        expect(ctrl.supportedLanguages.length).toEqual(2);
    });

});
```

It throws an exception on the statement: `var ctrl = controller('MyController');`

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `}` brace after `code:"pt_BR"`.

Comment: True. The missing } is a typo when entering the question. Still working on the issue

Comment: Since `SupportedLanguagesService` is using `$http`, you should be using `$httpBackend` to simulate an HTTP call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intead of `success` (which is an `$http` callback), you can change to a `then`, which is available on all promises. This will allow you to easily mock the promise (and not concern yourself with `$httpBackend`:

```
    SupportedLanguagesService.get().then(
        function(response) {
            self.supportedLanguages = response.data;
    });
```

Then, you need to use the controller's constructor and *then* call a `$digest`.  So, switching to this should get you there:

```
it('should get SupportedLanguages', function() {

    var ctrl = controller('MyController');
    rootScope.$digest();
    expect(ctrl.supportedLanguages.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

You can also simplify the setup code using `$q.when`:

```
var response = [{name:"English", code:"en"},{name:"Portugues", code:"pt_BR"}];
spyOn(SupportedLanguagesService, 'get').andReturn($q.when(response));
```

Comment: That wont work still because OP is using http promise chaining. $q does not have a success method it only has then method

Comment: @PSL do you mean the `$q.when` part?

Comment: I see...I think the OP needs `$httpBackend` here instead.

Comment: $q.when and deferred.promise as well. Actually uniot testing controller should mock just the service so it is fine but op should use `.then(` to work with $q.when or deferred.promise, i believe

Comment: The answer as given worked perfectly. First I needed to use 'then' instead of 'success' to resolve the promise in the controller and then I had to call $digest() after initializing the controller, not before.

Thank you David